# How close can a player on the defending side get to the player holding the disc?

Tags: ultimate-frisbee

Given:
In the case a player x, from team A holds the disc. 
Team A is on the offence, and team B is defending.

How close can player y, from team B get to player x when attempting to block a pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not indicated any particular rules set, I will use the [World Flying Disc Federation's rules](http://www.wfdf.org/sports/rules-of-play/cat_view/26-rules-of-play/32-ultimate). From the [Rules of Ultimate pdf](http://www.wfdf.org/sports/rules-of-play/doc_download/20-rules-of-ultimate), Article 18.1.1 states that marking infractions include:

> 18.1.1.3. “Disc Space” – any part of a defensive player is less than one disc diameter away from the torso of the thrower. However, if this situation is caused solely by movement of the thrower, it is not an infraction.

The final sentence is very important. If the thrower pivots to e.g. as far right as they can go, the marker can stand just to the left of his torso, but a disc's width away. This then prevents the thrower pivoting back to the left *and is completely legal*. I can't say I've ever experienced this in my own play though, either as marker or thrower.

Comment: In your example, though, it's *very* hard to picture one preventing the pivoting-back without running afoul of "straddling" (18.1.1.2)